# get current namespace from parent app in rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, rails-engines

I'm currently designing a rails engine that has the requirement to be embedded in a namespace in the parent app. i mean

```
Railsengine::Application.routes.draw do
    #this must not work
    mount MyEngine::Engine => "a path"

    #instead, the engine need to be embedded in a namespace
    #this work
    namespace :dummy do
       mount MyEngine::Engine => "search"
    end
end
```

My question is , how can i get the current namespace and know if the engine is called inside a namespace, everything inside the engine itself .

thanks